# Throttle messages in Vertx eventbus

Tags: vert.x, vertx-eventbus

Since eventbus in Vertx is made for asynchronous message passing, is it possible to throttle the rate at which these messages gets processed? If so can we achieve using worker verticles or do we have to create a separate thread group.
The point is event bus might be capable of queuing a million messages (i am guessing the number) where are the subsequent operations happening under workers/threads should not get flooded and ultimately make something down.
Please shred some light.

Answer (score 0):

Workers won't ever be flooded by EventBus, since the handlers will process only one message at a time.

What may happen, though, is that you may run out of memory, if you produce literally millions of unprocessed messages.

This usually wouldn't be the case, but you could attempt to solve that using the `Counter` in `SharedData`:

https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/shareddata/Counter.html

Comment: if the jvm gets restarted how does to preserve the messages to reprocess. Point i want to draw attention is if vertx itself is providing messaging capabilities and my application is built on vertx, i am not making sense to look for an another messaging system. Now I am sure if I can leverage or invest additional cost to get a messaging broker again.

Comment: EventBus doesn't preserve the messages, it's stated in the documentation. EventBus is not a message broker.

Comment: agreed @Alexey Soshin, assume preserving messages is trivial, in that case is it possible? SharedData comes only in the context of cluster, however i am running vertx app as standalone. Moreover eventBus/Vertx doesn't have api to findout the size of eventbus, meaning at anytime find the number of messages in eventBus

Comment: SharedData is accessible even if you don't use clustered mode: `vertx.sharedData().getLocalCounter("messageCount", (h) -> {})`